# Downloading and parsing research papers

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, regex, database

I am trying to write a script which gets a research paper from a website by calling their API and then traverse it sentence-wise with some conditions.

The paper is accessible in XML format. I am directly using the `nltk.sent_tokenize()` to break the relevant part of XML document into list of sentences and then searching for **"diseases"(number of diseases in my dataframe is 12000)** in every sentence using regex and if a match is found then i search for **"biomarkers"(this dataframe has 20000 rows and datatype of row is of type list with each list having an average of 2 values i.e. there are more than 40000 values which are to be matched)** in the same sentence. And finally the result is saved in database if disease and biomarker are found in the same sentence.

In the worst case steps taken to accomplish the task would be **900.000**(papers which are to be traversed)***15**(number of sentences in each paper)***12.000**(number of disease which are to be searched)***40.000**(number of marker which are to be searched).

At the moment the code is parsing 60-70 papers in an hour which is a bit too slow.

The following is the code which I have tried. I am searching for the existing bottlenecks in my code. Any suggestions to optimise the code would be highly appreciated.

````
import timeit
import mysql.connector
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import xml
import lxml.etree
from lxml import etree
import re
import math
import nltk 
import pandas as pd

start = timeit.default_timer()
print("start_time:", start)
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="biomarker")
mycursor = mydb.cursor() 
mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS papers_sentence_com_ppr")
mycursor.execute("create table papers_sentence_com_ppr (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, paper_id VARCHAR(255), marker VARCHAR(255),marker_id VARCHAR(255), disease_name VARCHAR(255),AUTHORS  TEXT, sentence  TEXT)")
mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE biomarker.papers_sentence_com_ppr CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8")
#mycursor.execute("create table papers (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, paper_id VARCHAR(255), count VARCHAR(255),disease_name VARCHAR(255))")
df1 = pd.read_sql_query("select name from biomarker.disease2", mydb)

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from biomarker.table_35", mydb)
print(df1)

biomarker_txt = df.at[2,'CA']
biomarker = biomarker_txt.split(" ")
print(len(biomarker))
#mycursor.execute("create table papers (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, paper_id VARCHAR(255), count VARCHAR(255),disease_name VARCHAR(255))")



urla='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=(%22biomarker%22%20OR%20%22biomarkers%22%20OR%20%22biological%20marker%22%20OR%20%22biological%20markers%22)%20%20AND%20%20(LANG%3A%22eng%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22en%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22us%22)%20AND%20%20(HAS_ABSTRACT%3Ay)%20%20AND%20%20(SRC%3A%22PPR%22)&resultType=idlist&pageSize=1000&format=xml'
urlb='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=(%22biomarker%22%20OR%20%22biomarkers%22%20OR%20%22biological%20marker%22%20OR%20%22biological%20markers%22)%20%20AND%20%20(LANG%3A%22eng%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22en%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22us%22)%20AND%20%20(HAS_ABSTRACT%3Ay)%20%20AND%20%20(SRC%3A%22PPR%22)&resultType=idlist&pageSize=1000&format=xml'


array1 = []
re1=requests.get(urla)
root = ET.fromstring(re1.content)
for hitCount in root.iter('hitCount'):
    hit_count=int(hitCount.text)
result_value=hit_count
hit_count1=hit_count/1000
hit_count=math.ceil(hit_count1)

hit_count=10




counter1=0
counter3=0
y=0
i=1


for x in range(hit_count):
    
    re1=requests.get(urla)
    root1 = ET.fromstring(re1.content)
    
    for id in root1.iter('id'):
        id_text=id.text
       
        array1.append(id.text)
    for nextCursorMark in root1.iter('nextCursorMark'):
       
        counter3=counter3+1
        print(counter3)
        urla=urlb
        urla =urla+"&cursorMark="+nextCursorMark.text







for i in range(result_value):# will run 900.000 times for 900.000 papers
    print("paper no:", i,)
    paper_id=(array1[i]) #array1 contains list of paper ids
    print("paper_id:", paper_id)       
    make_url= 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=ext_id:'+paper_id+'&resultType=core&format=xml'
    re2=requests.get(make_url)
    root2 = ET.fromstring(re2.content)
    for abstractText in root2.iter('abstractText'):
           
            abstract_text_without_tags= re.sub(r"<[^>]*>"," ",abstractText.text )#extract the relevant xml part
            
           
            
            
            nltk_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(abstract_text_without_tags)#break the text into sentences
            
            for text in range(len(nltk_tokens)):#depends on the length of text
                    
                    for zz in range(len(df)):#df has 20.000 rows
                        biomarker_txt=((df.at[zz,'CA'])) 
                        biomarker = biomarker_txt.split(" ")# a cell could have more than value which are separated by an space
                        for tt in range(len(biomarker)):
                            if len(biomarker[tt])>2:
                                matches_for_marker = re.findall(rf"\b{re.escape(biomarker[tt])}\b", nltk_tokens[text])
                                if len(matches_for_marker)!=0:
                                    for y in range(len(df1)):
                                        disease_name=(df1.at[y,'name'])
                                        
                                        regex_for_dis = rf"\b{disease_name}\b"
                                        
                        
                                        matches_for_dis= re.findall(regex_for_dis, nltk_tokens[text], re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
                                        #matches_for_dis = [re.findall(rf"\b{(df1.at[y,'name'])}\b", nltk_tokens[text], re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE) for y in  range(len(df1))]
                       
                                        
                                        if len(matches_for_dis)!=0:
                                            
                            
                                            for firstPublicationDate in root2.iter('firstPublicationDate'):
                                                firstPublicationDate=firstPublicationDate.text
                                            for authorString in root2.iter('authorString'):
                                                counter1=counter1+1
                                            
                                            mycursor.execute("insert into papers_sentence_com_ppr (id, paper_id,firstPublicationDate, marker,marker_id, disease_name, AUTHORS, sentence) values (%s,%s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,%s)", (counter1, paper_id,firstPublicationDate, biomarker[tt],(df.at[zz,'Entry']), (df1.at[y,'name']), authorString.text, nltk_tokens[text]))
                                            #print("***********************************************************DATABASE_ENTRY*************************************************************\n")
                                            mydb.commit()






```
````

Comment: Please show all of the code, including where `result_value` is initialized

Comment: i have added the rest of the code

Comment: 15 sentences in a paper?  That seems very low.

Answer (score 2):

Currently all of your code exists in one global pile, with no functions, submodules or classes. Introduce some of those.

I see that your password is shown as blank for the database. A few things:

- I really hope that the password is not *actually* blank, and that you've instead omitted it for the purposes of review. Please don't use a blank password.
- This script should not be logging in as root, but rather as a permissions-limited user.
- Store your database login password somewhere else, in some kind of secure wallet, cred store, etc.

Wrap your connection and cursor objects in `with` context managers.

You should definitely not be dropping an entire table in this script. If anything, maybe you should be `truncate`ing it to delete all of its data; but definitely don't drop it.

You have a pile of unused imports; all of these:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml
import lxml.etree
from lxml import etree
```

need to be deleted.

Change your URL construction so that instead of this thing:

```
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=(%22biomarker%22%20OR%20%22biomarkers%22%20OR%20%22biological%20marker%22%20OR%20%22biological%20markers%22)%20%20AND%20%20(LANG%3A%22eng%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22en%22%20OR%20LANG%3A%22us%22)%20AND%20%20(HAS_ABSTRACT%3Ay)%20%20AND%20%20(SRC%3A%22PPR%22)&resultType=idlist&pageSize=1000&format=xml
```

you have a well-defined method that accepts a session, forms a parameter dictionary, validates the response and parses an ET:

```
def get_ebi(session: Session, **kwargs: str) -> ET.ElementTree:
    query = (
        '("biomarker" OR "biomarkers" OR "biological marker" OR "biological markers") '
        'AND (LANG:"eng" OR LANG:"en" OR LANG:"us") '
        'AND (HAS_ABSTRACT:y) '
        'AND (SRC:"PPR")'
    )
    with session.get(
        'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search',
        params={
            'format': 'xml',
            'resultType': 'idlist',
            'pageSize': 1_000,
            'query': query,
            **kwargs,
        },
        stream=True,
    ) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        root = ET.parse(response.raw)

    return root


with Session() as sess:
    root = get_ebi(sess)
    for hitCount in root.iter('hitCount'):
        hit_count = int(hitCount.text)
    result_value = hit_count
    hit_count1 = hit_count / 1_000
    hit_count = math.ceil(hit_count1)
```

That aside, your code is filled with things that simply don't make sense. You overwrite variables:

```
hit_count=math.ceil(hit_count1)
hit_count=10
```

You have mystical, impenetrable variable names:

```
array1 = []
counter1=0
counter3=0
y=0
i=1
```

You have variables with slightly different names that do completely different things:

```
for hitCount in root.iter('hitCount'):
    hit_count=int(hitCount.text)
```

That last example also improperly iterates through all `hitCount` elements when it should only pay attention to the first.

You shadow built-ins:

```
    for id in root1.iter('id'):
```

You name variables that are the exact opposite of what they contain; `text` will actually contain an integer:

```
for text in range(len(nltk_tokens)):
```

You do a commit in your innermost loop, when it should probably hold off until much later, possibly the end of the script.

You should attempt to address these issues, particularly organization into subroutine methods, and then post a new question.

Comment: Many thanks!! I will make the mentioned changes and hopefully the process would get faster.

Comment: @sanjeev_gautam You can also post a new question with your updated code. Once you have addressed the obvious shortcomings of your current code, someone might find a good way to speed it up significantly.

Comment: yep, i will do that.  i have made some changes but i guess the function calling is making the process even slower.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put a `FULLTEXT` index in the middle of the algorithm.  It is likely to be faster than other techniques since it is effectively an inverted index of word=>sentence; this can be used for names of both diseases and biomarkers.  Furthermore, it can handle multi-word names.

Parse the XML, put one sentence per row into the table.  That will be only about 14M rows; not bad.

```
FULLTEXT(sentence)
```

Searching for a single combination is easy and very fast:

```
SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(sentence)
             AGAINST(+"disease name" +"biomarker" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But that is not practical, since you would need to do it 480M times.

So, let's instead search for only one name at time and capture the the info.  This will take 40K + 12K queries, something like

```
UPDATE t
    SET a_disease = ?
    WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST(+? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Ditto for another column, `a_marker`.

Then, poof, this gives you the entire answer at the sentence level:

```
SELECT paper_id, sentence_id, a_disease, a_marker
    FROM t
    WHERE a_disease IS NOT NULL
      AND a_marker IS NOT NULL;
```

A little more work with a `GROUP BY` would boil that down to the disease-marker pairs, by "paper":

```
SELECT paper_id,
       a_disease,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a_marker SEPARATOR ", " ORDER BY a_marker) AS markers
    FROM (
        SELECT paper_id, a_disease, a_marker
            FROM t
            WHERE a_disease IS NOT NULL
              AND a_marker IS NOT NULL
         ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY a_disease, paper_id
    ORDER BY a_disease, paper_id;
```

(Or some other grouping/ordering.)

One flaw:  If one sentence mentions multiple diseases or markers, this does not handle it.